# linklabel to open excel file vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linklabel

Well i want to do something but i don't find a way to do it.
I have 3 linklabels in a form as you can see in the picture.

[image]

I want so open an excel file when i click in a linklabel. i tried this:

```
    Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked

 aplicacaoexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\LPO1BRG\Desktop\Software Fiabilidade\Maquinas2", ReadOnly:=True)    

End Sub
```

But it didn't work. Does anyone can help me with this?? 
I find some codes but all of them only open url's.

Comment: So is the issue you don't know the name of the file(or extension) in the folder? Either way I think one of the answers here should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157385/how-to-open-a-workbook-specifying-its-path

Comment: what do you mean by `OPEN` here ? your code cannot open display the excel file .. do you mean you want to open the file in excel itself ?

Comment: and your code will read `Maquinas2` as a folder rather than a file as you missed to provide the file extension

Comment: @JacobH , the provided link will not help …. an the question is itself isn't clear

Comment: @zackraiyan I mean, the link clearly demonstrates how to open a file using `Workbooks.Open` using a path to a file. I am pretty sure it is not different between vba and .net. It is clear to you and I that the problem is a missing extension and that the OP does not understand. I think it's worth giving the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @JacobH  i forgot to write here the file extension. To be clear, i want to open the excel file and display it. When I use this code it only opens the excel file but i can't see it opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified that the instance of the Excel app should be visible. Add this ..

```
aplicacaoexcel.Visible = True
```

just before the line ..

```
aplicacaoexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\LPO1BRG\Desktop\Software Fiabilidade\Maquinas2", ReadOnly:=True)
```